# SymPy: Expression for Summation of Symbols in a List

Tags: python, sympy

I'm writing a program that evaluates the power series `sum_{m=0}{oo} a[m]x^m`, where `a[m]` is recursively defined: `a[m]=f(a[m-1])`. I am generating symbols as follows:

```
a = list(sympy.symbols(' '.join([('a%d' % i) for i in range(10)])))
for i in range(1, LIMIT):
   a[i] = f_recur(a[i-1], i-1)
```

This lets me refer to the symbols `a0,a1,...,a9` using `a[0],a[1],...,a[9]`, and `a[m]` is a function of `a[m-1]` given by `f_recur`.

Now, I hope code up the summation as follows:

```
m, x, y = sympy.symbols('m x y')
y = sympy.Sum(a[m]*x**m, (m, 0, 10))
```

But, `m` is not an integer so `a[m]` throws an Exception.

In this situation, where symbols are stored in a list, how would you code the summation? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SymPy's `Sum` is designed as a sum with a *symbolic* index. You want a sum with a concrete index running through 0, ... 9. This could be Python's `sum`

```
y = sum([a[m]*x**m for m in range(10)])
```

or, which is preferable from the performance point of view ([relevant issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/13945))

```
y = sympy.Add(*[a[m]*x**m for m in range(10)])
```

In either case, `m` is not a symbol but an integer.

Answer (score 1):

I have a work-around that does not use `sympy.Sum`:

```
x = sympy.symbols('x')
y = a[0]*x**0
for i in range(1, LIMIT):
    y += a[i]*x**i
```

This does the job, but `sympy.Sum` is not used.

Answer (score 0):

Use IndexedBase instead of Symbol:

```
>>> a = IndexedBase('a')
>>> Sum(x**m*a[m],(m,1,3))
Sum(a[m]*x**m, (m, 1, 3))
>>> _.doit()
a[1]*x + a[2]*x**2 + a[3]*x**3
```